# No pointer in the specified memory location. What's wrong with delete op?

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I am trying to make an example for char pointers and use of delete operator. Code is very simple:

```
char name[] = "subject";
char *nameptr = name;
cout <<"&nameptr: " <<&nameptr<< endl;
delete [] nameptr;
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
*** glibc detected ***  free(): invalid pointer: 0xbf9e4194 ***
```

and I know nameptr points out to location 0xbf9e4184, from the output.
There is no pointer points out to that location (0xbf9e4194).
I believe it's something to do with my use of delete but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Please don't program by guessing. Read a good book that teaches the language systematically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only call `delete` or `delete []` on memory allocated with `new` or `new []`, respectively. There's no need to free string literals like `"subject"`.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable information @godel9. I have one more question. I can't print out anything else after I call delete. Does it have to be called at the end of the main?

Comment: In your example, you never need to call `delete []`. Generally speaking, you should have one `delete/delete[]` call for each `new/new[]` call. If you never call `new`, you never need to call `delete`.

Answer (score 3):

Examine your code statement by statement:

Here you have an array of characters, containing "subject":

```
char name[] = "subject";
```

Here you define a pointer, pointing to the aforementioned array:

```
char *nameptr = name;
```

Here **you `delete[]` something that you did *not* allocate using `new[]`** (in fact, `name` was *not* allocated using `new[]`, you didn't write: `char * name = new char[...]`):

```
delete [] nameptr;
```

So, an error is (correctly) detected, because you tried to free something that was not allocated on the heap using `new` (or `malloc`).